# Button for link doesn't work in ie7/ie8

Tags: html

I have a button which takes the user to another page.  I could just use a link but I want it to look like a button.  It works fine in everything except IE7 and IE8 but I have no idea why?

```
<div id="print_version">
          <a href="report_print.php?audit=<? echo $audit_id; ?>" target="_blank">
          <input type="button"value="Print Report"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: you forgot a space? `input type="button" value="Print Report">`

Comment: well spotted but no change with space

Comment: Also, doing this is a bad idea, you can try `<input type="button" value="Print Report" onclick="javascript: window.location(report_print.php?audit=<? echo $audit_id; ?>)" />`

Comment: and you forgot to close end the input `<input type="button"value="Print Report" />`

Comment: @AlexandruCalin Why use `<input>`?  Use a `<button>`.

Comment: @Eric You need to know the `DOCTYPE` to know if that's appropriate

Comment: @Madbreaks USE BUTTON!? he's using ie7, ie8 for got sake, use INPUT!

Comment: Style your link to look like a button and forget about the input.

Comment: Thanks, but that still does the same thing, nothing.  Out of interest though, why is it a bad idea?

Comment: Just use Javascript, it will work 100%. Except if you're targeting potential non-javascript users; Or style it with css as @Jrod said :)

Comment: @AlexandruCalin Ha. Good point, my bad.

Comment: @AlexandruCalin, thanks for that but I'm afraid the javascript version of the button doesn't work in any of the browsers

Comment: Are you 100% certain? i'm pretty sure i did this on win98, IE6, and it worked 10 billions years ago.

Comment: yup, dead certain, I tried your version, just pasted it but nothing, so I tried it again without the word javascript in the onclick argument but still nada

Comment: @AlexandruCalin, this worked <input type="button" value="Print Report" onclick="parent.location='report_print.php?audit=<? echo $audit_id; ?>'" />.  Problem is it doesn't open it in a new page, but thanks for all your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the input and use a styled `<a>` tag.

**HTML**

```
<div id="print_version">
     <a class="btn" href="report_print.php?audit=<?php echo $audit_id; ?>" target="_blank">Print Report</a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.btn {
    -moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
    -moz-border-left-colors: none;
    -moz-border-right-colors: none;
    -moz-border-top-colors: none;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #FFFFFF, #E6E6E6);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    border-color: #E6E6E6 #E6E6E6 #A2A2A2;
    border-image: none;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) inset, 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    color: #333333;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding: 4px 14px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

CSS is compliments of twitter bootstrap. http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/